# Firefox local storage not available in other tab

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm creating a firefox extension. I want to use localStorage as a global variable for whole browser. But it is working only for the tab where it was saved. I'm not able to read this value in other tab. How  I can make it to be accessible from any tab, or what may be the possible issues ?

I use it like:

```
localStorage.getItem('variable')
localStorage.setItem('variable','value')
```

To be more precise, I'm injecting the javascript code into the page when it was loaded. and from injected code i want to save my value to localstorage.

tabs have different url. and my code is trying to use the localstorage when page loaded. but it checking if the localStorage value exists like this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('variable')){ ... }
```

Comment: does the other tab have the same origin?  If not, no dice...

Comment: Are you doing it in that order?  Getting the item before setting it?

Comment: @DavidStarkey yes i'm trying to read it before update it. but before reading it i'm checking if it exists. check my post update to see the code how i'm checking

Comment: @Jigberto Are you going to answer Alnitak's question? If the two pages aren't in the same subdomain, they won't be able to "share" it

Comment: tabs have different domain address.

Comment: @Jigberto if _tabs have different domain address_ then no, you cannot access `localStorage` between tabs. If tabs have same domain, it should work.

Comment: @KevinBoucher is there any solution for what i need ?

Comment: @Jigberto Assuming the disparate servers have access to each other or a common resource you could employ a server-side solution for this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `localStorage` as a global variable

```
localStorage is also the same as globalStorage[location.hostname], with the exception 
of being scoped to an HTML5 origin (scheme + hostname + non-standard port) and 
localStorage being an instance of Storage as opposed to 
globalStorage[location.hostname] being an instance of StorageObsolete which is covered 
below. For example, http://example.com is not able to access the same localStorage 
object as https://example.com but they can access the same globalStorage item. 
localStorage is a standard interface while globalStorage is non-standard so you 
shouldn't rely on these.

Please note that setting a property on globalStorage[location.hostname] does not set 
it on localStorage and extending Storage.prototype does not affect globalStorage 
items, only extending StorageObsolete.prototype does.
```

Consider using `globalStorage` and then setting `localStorage` where need be.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: You shouldn't suggest using something that is obsolete and non-standard

Comment: It **doesn't** work, unless you're using a FireFox version between 2 and 13. Why would you ever think that's a good solution?

Comment: @Ian OP says "Firefox" not "Firefox 1" nor "Firefox 20".  This solution covers several versions.  If you have a better option, please do share.

Comment: Sure, "several versions". Which is about 12% of Firefox's market share. And no, I don't have a better option, I never said or acted like I did. But surely there's a more complete way because of how extensions work. Normally, browser extensions have some "background" process running (which can either store the data or some form of permanent storage), and there's usually some way for the DOM to talk to the extension, so it should be easy to put those ideas together. I've never specifically developed *Firefox* extensions, so I don't know the specifics.